# Mathematical modelling and set-builder notation. Help with interpretation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to work my way through a white paper on room pricing for hotel rooms. I'm working on upgrading my math knowledge with MOOCs, but I'm running into problems that haven't been covered yet, and I'm not sure where to look.

For example, the following incorporates some set-builder notation, I believe. If anyone could help me by either explaining what I'm not understanding or by pointing me in the right direction for topics to study, that would be awesome.

*"To formulate this model, we define a stay in the hotel by
(a,L,k), where ‘a’ is the first night of the stay, ‘L’ is the length
of the stay and ‘k’ the price class. Further, denote the set of
stays that make use of night ‘l’ by $N_l$, where $N_l = \{(a,L,k):
l = a: a + L - 1\}$."*

I haven't seen the colon (:) used before, only pipe (|). But another MathExchange post says that the colon (:) also means "such that."

So, this is basically saying to include stay $(a,L,k)$ such that the first night (a) equals the specified night, (l), such that the first night (a) plus the length-of-stay (L) minus 1.  If that interpretation is correct, I still don't understand the third component. The second component could be evaluated as either true or false, but how is the third component evaluated? There's no comparison operator.

As this is my first post, I hope I've formatted everything correctly.

Thank-you
AF

Comment: I think that it might be a typo; I've never seen two pipes or two colons in set builder notation before, and as you have correctly noted it would seem that there is no formula there, just an expression. I hope someone can post an answer for you.

Comment: It seems like a typo to me, too.  I think they mean $N_l = \{(a,L,k):
a \le l \le a + L - 1\}$  That would be all the stays where the guest was at the hotel on day $l$.  The first day of the stay is $a$ and the last is $a+L-1$.